# Equivalence of Definitions for $T_1$

Tags: general-topology

A topological space $(X,T)$ is $T_1$ (or Fréchet) if and only if for every $x\in X$, $\{x\}$ is the intersection of all neighborhoods $N\in N_x$

I have to use the following definition:

$(X,T)$ is $T_1$ if for $x,y\in X$ exists a neighborhood $ U_x$ of $x$ not containing $y$ and a neighborhood $ U_y$ of $y$ not containing $x$.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I added LaTeX formatting to your question. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "$N$ neighbourhoods" - do you mean that $\{x\} = \bigcap \{ N \mid N \in N_x \}$, were $N_x$ means the neighbourhoods of $x$?

Comment: What definition of T$_1$ are you given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\langle X,\mathcal{T}\rangle$ is a T$_1$ space, then for all $x\in X$ and all $y\in X\setminus\{x\},$ there is some $U\in\mathcal T$ such that $x\in U$ and $y\notin U$. That is, there is some $U\in\mathcal N_x$ such that $y\notin U$, so that $y\notin\bigcap\mathcal N_x.$ This holds for all $y\in X\setminus\{x\},$ so since $x\in\bigcap\mathcal N_x,$ what can you conclude?

Suppose that $\langle X,\mathcal T\rangle$ is *not* a T$_1$ space. Then there is some $x\in X$ and some $y\in X\setminus\{x\}$ such that for all $U\in\mathcal T$ with $x\in U$ we have $y\in U$. That is, $y\in U$ for all $U\in\mathcal N_x,$ so $y\in\bigcap\mathcal N_x,$ and so $\{x\}\neq\bigcap\mathcal N_x.$

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is $T1$, then $$\forall x,y \in X. (x\neq y\Rightarrow (\exists U^{\text{open}}. x\in U^{\text{open}} \land y\notin U^{\text{open}}))\text{,} \quad (*)$$
so $x$ is the only point in the intersection of all open neighbourhoods of $x$. Similar argument works in the opposite direction: choose $x,y\in X$. If $x\neq y$ and $(*)$ holds,
there exists open neighbourhood of $x$ which does not contain $y$, so $X$ is $T1$.